# How can I move a project initialized with git to other place

Tags: git

I made a project of Python using Git, so I use git init that created me a .git folder. 
Then I moved this project to a new workspace that contains another .git. 
When I commit changes in this workspace, the original project changes also.

What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: Could you run `ls` on the two separate directories?

Answer (score 0):

The root directory of a git repo is the directory that contains the `.git` directory<sup>1</sup>, so two projects for which you want separate repos *cannot* share root directories.

If your goal is to group these two projects together into a "super project", you can create a new parent directory for both, e.g.:

```
super-project
├── sub-project1
│   ├── .git
│   (all the files of project 1)
│
└── sub-project2
    ├── .git
    (all the files of project 2)
```

Many IDEs will respect this setup. For example, JetBrains IDE for Python, PyCharm, can handle that your project contains two parts with separate source control.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are advanced usage of git where this is not true. In any case, projects needing separate repos still cannot share root directories.